# how do I use a value saved in service through component in other services in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-services

I am trying to set a value through component

```
export class SomeComponent {
constructor(service:SomeService){
  }
count =0 ;
  onRefresh(){
  this.service.count = 1;
  }
}
```

I want to use this value in the service like

```
SomeService{
count:any;
doSomething(){
    //use count value here
    console.log('count value saved thru compoent',count);
    } 
}
```

All I want to do is use the value stored through component in some service. When I tried this, I am getting an undefined count.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a great answer since I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is a simple solution based on the information provided without too many tweaks.

I made a button in the AppComponent HTML that will call a function called `onRefresh()` in order to show how this is passed from a function. Once this button is clicked, here is the function that will be run:

`<button type="button" (click)="onRefresh()">Count Button in Service</button>`

```
onRefresh() {
  this.service.count = 1;
  this.service.doSomething();
}
```

Here is the code for the service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SomeServiceService {
  count: any;

  doSomething() {
    console.log("count value saved thru compoent", this.count);
  }
}
```

No when you click the button, it will set the service count var to 1, and log it to the console. Hope this helps. [Here is a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-otldce) with the same code provided above